# How to reverse the format of date

Tags: javascript

I want to reverse the date format as dd-mm-yyyy
  When I'm trying to just replace it with a string its working fine.

```
var Arr = [{
    'name': 'AA',
    'startDate': '2019-09-26',
    'endDate': '2019-09-26'
}, {
    'name': 'BB',
    'startDate': '2019-09-26',
    'endDate': '2019-09-26'
}, {
    'name': 'CC',
    'startDate': '2019-09-26',
    'endDate': '2019-09-26'
}, {
    'name': 'DD',
    'startDate': '2019-09-26',
    'endDate': '2019-09-26'
}];
Arr.forEach((item) => item.startDate = item.startDate.split("-").reverse().join("-"));
console.log(Arr);
```

Comment: what is `item.Start_Date__c`?

Comment: Your code works as is (barring the typo @Thomas pointed out). What's the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a simple function which converts the passed date string into desired format and returns it to the caller. You also need to make changes inside `Arr.forEach()`.

> **Note:** For more detailed use of forEach(), you can check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach.

So, you can try like this.

```
function getDDMMYYYY(dateString) {
    return dateString.split('-').reverse().join('-')
}

// start
var Arr = [{
    'name': 'AA',
    'startDate': '2019-09-26',
    'endDate': '2019-09-26'
}, {
    'name': 'BB',
    'startDate': '2019-09-26',
    'endDate': '2019-09-26'
}, {
    'name': 'CC',
    'startDate': '2019-09-26',
    'endDate': '2019-09-26'
}, {
    'name': 'DD',
    'startDate': '2019-09-26',
    'endDate': '2019-09-26'
}];

Arr.forEach((item, index) => {
        Arr[index]["startDate"] = getDDMMYYYY(item.startDate)
        Arr[index]["endDate"] = getDDMMYYYY(item.endDate)
})

console.log(Arr)
/*
[
  { name: 'AA', startDate: '26-09-2019', endDate: '26-09-2019' },
  { name: 'BB', startDate: '26-09-2019', endDate: '26-09-2019' },
  { name: 'CC', startDate: '26-09-2019', endDate: '26-09-2019' },
  { name: 'DD', startDate: '26-09-2019', endDate: '26-09-2019' }
]
*/
```